# How to create a series of neural networks using neuralnet in R?

Tags: r

I would like to change this:

```
library(neuralnet)
nn1 <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)
nn1 <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)
```

into something like this:

```
nn[1] <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)
nn[2] <- neuralnet(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)
```

neuralnet creates networks as lists. I have tried creating a list of lists like this:

```
AllNets <- list(nn1, nn2)
```

But when I try go back to use a particular network it doesn't behave like a neural network although I can't see any difference using str():

```
plot(AllNets[2])
nntemp = AllNets[2]
nntemp = unlist(AllNets[2])
nntemp = unlist(AllNets[2], recursive = FALSE)
plot(nntemp)
```

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I needed double bracket notation:

plot(AllNets[[2]]) will work.